# I want data input on multiple access forms to go into same record of access table

Tags: forms, ms-access, datatable, report

I have an initial form that clears my data table when I select ‘begin’ (table name AUS_Table), and by clicking a command on each form it will direct you to another form to initial depending on your yes or no answer. The current problem is I have one table with About 30 fields, but when the user uses a different form respectively, the data goes into the next record in the table. I want all the data from each form (15 total), to go into the first record in the table.

Because the data goes into different records, it does not get brought into the report when trying to print it. It creates multiple reports, once based on each record, so every report has one piece of information on it.

[Intro Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR62s.png)

[Table that I want all data in same record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3L4d.png)

[second form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwYT4.png)

Comment: First form creates record, other forms should open and edit same record. This is very odd arrangement. Instead of multiple forms, why not a single form and arrange data on a Tab control? Why are you 'clearing' table?

Comment: Definitely unconventional, but I want the user to only have one option if they select a certain answer (yes, no). The report being emailed to me is a single time use, and different for every user. Essentially it’s their way of cancelling their benefits and has to be completed each time they go on a set of active duty orders. 

Is there a simple place to look up how I can have the second, third, fourth, etc. form that is opened edit the record? I’m unfamiliar with this. Thank you!

Comment: Set the Form's Allow Additions/Allow Deletions to No in the properties of the subsequent forms.

Comment: Retain record ID somewhere so it can be referenced when needed. Or open each subsequent form filtered to that ID. I really think this can all be managed with a single form, but that is an opinion. Your issue is really with design - there are many ways to accomplish what you want. There is no code provided for analysis and therefore question not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: The allow additions/allow deletions almost worked, but now when I go to form view, the form is totally blank. I can only see if it’s in design view.

Comment: With those settings, should see existing records and NewRecord row not available. Edit question to provide code for analysis.

Comment: I added a few images, but I don't have any codes to use currently. I set the allow additions/allow deletions to no, no, which for a second it put the data into the same record (the first line in the table). But now the forms go blank if I select 'next' on the form prior to getting there

Comment: Each form must save record edit before opening next form. Open next form filtered to ID.

Comment: I may have it wrong but I tried this: DoCmd.OpenForm "8_FSA", , "[ID]", "[ID]=" & Me.ID and still eror

Comment: What error? Using too many arguments. `DoCmd.OpenForm "8_FSA", , , "[ID]=" & Me.ID`.